# R: How to use list elements like arguments in ellipsis?

Tags: r, list, arguments, wrapper, ellipsis

I'm not sure if I labelled my question correct, but I give it a shot:

I want to use a package with a function which uses an ellipsis, `func(...)`. All my arguments of class `My_Class` are in a list. As I have quite a lot of arguments, I'd like to avoid `func(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. So ideally I'd like to do `func( my_list )`. The problem is that the function looks like this

```
function(...) {
  cl <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  names <- lapply(cl[[2]],as.character)  
  ev <- parent.frame()
  classes <- unlist(lapply(names,function(name){class(get(name,envir=ev))}))    
  if( !all( classes == "My_Class" ) ) { 
    stop("an argument to ... is not a My_Class")
  }
}
```

So passing a list doesn't work.

I also tried `func(my_list[[1]], my_list[[2]])` and `func(as.expression(my_list[[1]]))`, but even they do not work. As `func` treats the arguments as characters, `func(my_list[[1]])` becomes `chr [1:3] "[[" "my_list" "1"` inside, and `get(name,envir=ev)` crashes. I also tried `do.call(func, my_list)` but this again crashes as `my_list` is evaluated, therefore `name` inside the function is no longer a `character` but a `My_CLass` and again `get(name,envir=ev)` crashes.

**So my question:** How can I accomplish to hand in a list without changing the package / underlying function? I thought about writing a wrapper, but I'm stuck as I do not even can `func(my_list[[1]])` make work. Maybe I'm just missing the correct term for my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but don't I have to use this inside func()? I didn't want to change function, i.e. the R package, but to write a script and use the function as it is. Sorry if I didn't understood correctly. What would an example code be with my_list?

Comment: Response to comment which disappeared: `do.call(func, my_list)` results in `func` being called with `My_Class` object, which is correct. But the way the test is written, it treats `my_list` as an character to get the object by name `get(name,envir=ev)` which doesn't work. E.g., usually you have `func(arg1)` which works if `arg1` is `My_Class` object. Then `func` does `get("arg1",envir=ev)` which works. If `arg1 = 1`, then `do.call(fun, arg1)` results in `get("1",envir=ev)` which doesn't work.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, that won't work either because the item in the list has to exist as an object in the `parent.frame` of the function.  This function is just mindboggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but I'm mystified by the design choices in that function:

```
lst <- list(
  a=structure(1:3, class="My_Class"), 
  b=structure(letters[1:3], class="My_Class")
)
env <- list2env(lst)
call <- as.call(append(list(fun), names(lst)))
eval(call, env)
```

To trick the function into working, you have to evaluate it in an environment where your list items are objects (this is what `list2env` does, creates that environment).

The terrible thing about that function is that it looks up objects in `parent.frame` based on their names, assuming that the `...` values are indeed names.  I really don't understand why that function doesn't just do something like:

```
if(!all(vapply(list(...), class, "") == "My_Class")) stop(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I was about to write an example but you were faster. And also thanks for the explanation, maybe I will suggest it. At first I thought it is to gain time that `match.call` is used instead of `list(...)`, but if one is looking them up anyway it may not be helpful.

Comment: Also, realizing that you don't even need to create an environment; you can just evaluate directly with the list as the `envir` argument.