# R: How to use as.call with vectors as optional parameters?

Tags: r, list, call, optional-parameters

I'm trying to write a wrapper for a function in order to use lists as input. I **cannot** change the function itself, therefore I need a workaround outside of it. I use `as.call()` and it works without optional arguments, but I fail to make it work when I have vectors as optional arguments.

Example:

```
# function I cannot change
func <- function(..., opt=c(1,2)) {
    cl <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    names <- lapply(cl[[2]],as.character)  
    ev <- parent.frame()
    classes <- unlist(lapply(names,function(name){class(get(name,envir=ev))}))    
    print(c(opt,names, classes))
}

a <- structure(1:3, class="My_Class")
b <- structure(letters[1:3], class="My_Class")

lst <- list(a, b)
names(lst) <- c("a","b")

# Normal result
func(a,b,opt=c(3,4))

# This should give the same but it doesn't
call <- as.call(append(list(func), list(names(lst), opt=c(3,4))))
g <- eval(call, lst)
```

Instead of a `list` as optional argument, I also tried `c()`, but this doesn't work either. Does anybody have a suggestion or a help page? `?call` wasn't to clear about my problem.

(I already asked a previous question to the topic here: [R: How to use list elements like arguments in ellipsis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436692/r-how-to-use-list-elements-like-arguments-in-ellipsis) , but left out the detail about the optional parameter and cannot figure it out now.)

Comment: Normally I would suggest `do.call(func, c(lst, list(opt=c(3,4))))`. However, that doesn't work with your function, which you claim you cannot change. However, it would be the normal way to pass arguments from a list to a function. So, your function can be considered to do things in a non-standard way.

Comment: You may not be able to change `func`, but you sure as hell can write a new function that does what you want it to.

Comment: What's so critical about using `lists` as input? It's not at all obvious what sort of arguments `func` is expected to take, but it's certainly easy to convert the `list` elements to some other type of object which you could feed   to `func` in a loop or `*apply`.

Comment: Roland: I agree but since I want to use a package where it is implemented like this, my only option is to write the package maintainer. I'll do that, but for the moment I'd like to have a working solution. But thanks for pointing out how it should be used: This way I can work on a proposition to improve the function :)

Comment: Hong Ooi: That's true, but as there are multiple functions like this, it's a bit of copy-paste and rewriting the whole package. In the worst case I'll do that.

Comment: Carl Witthoft: It doesn't have to be a list. func now takes two objects a and b, and originally I have them in a list. I just want to avoid to do a <- my_list[[1]]; b <- my_list[[2]]; func(a,b). Instead I want `func(my_list)` or `obj <- transform(my_list): func(obj)` as I don't know how many a's and b's are there. If you have another suggesting than a list to circumvent the (...), I'd be very interested. I'll have a look at `*apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the same result for me under both versions

```
call <- as.call(c(list(quote(func)), lapply(names(lst), as.name), list(opt=c(3,4))))
g <- eval(call, lst)
```

EDIT: as per Hadley's suggestions in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me again! This solution is not yet satisfying as I don't want to explicitly type every a and b, that's why I want to hand in a list in the first place. Is there a possibility like `apply(quote,names(list))` or something? I'll have a look at `quote`, it seems to be a promising idea.

Comment: @user2075339, see modification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving me! I try to get better to solve stuff myself, but after 3 days trying I gave up on this. Do you have any recommendation where I should start to read to learn things like these?

Comment: The [R manual "R Language Definition"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) is a good resource.  It may seem a little cryptic at first, but it's definitely worth the effort to sit at your R terminal and try to understand exactly what they explain.  Once you understand it properly, I would challenge you to re-write the functions in the package you're using the correct way so they work as expected, and submit them to the maintainer for replacement ;).

Comment: @BrodieG The combination of `append` and `c` is rather confusing. Also using `quote(func)` instead of `func` would lead to a more natural call.

Comment: @hadley, agreed about `append/c`, I was editing an existing line of code and just go lazy (I considered fixing it, but then had to leave).  Fair point about `quote(func)` too.

Comment: I changed it accordingly. I'll have a look at your sources and hope one day I'll learn to solve stuff like this by myself.